# Cannot disable button in javascript after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following js file and I want to disable a button after my AJAX call:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  const runField = $('input[id=run]')
  const runButton = $('.btn-run')
  const saveButton = $('.btn-save')

  runButton.on('click', function(event) {
    console.log('run clicked')
    runField.val(1)
    event.preventDefault()
    $('.btn-run').prop('disabled', true)
    console.log($('.btn-run').prop('disabled'))
    runCode()
    $('.btn-run').prop('disabled', false)
  })
})
```

`runCode()` is my AJAX function here, but when I used `.prop('disabled', true)` the button was still not disabled, even though the following logged line returned true in my console. I made sure all the properties like ID's are correct. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to use promises.

Comment: You are re-enabling the button right after disabling it. You need to re-enable only when the AJAX call is finished. To clarify, your code will not wait on `runCode` before advancing to the next line (since `runCode`) is an asynchronous function. As @Slaks says, you need to use promises or a callback to re-enable the button.

Comment: Hi SLaks, can you give more info on that since I'm new to javascript?

Comment: change the last line to $('.btn-run').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: OHH got you. thx!

Comment: @Keith: That won't change anythng.

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous hence before of runCode disable after runCode enable but it is not fulfulled your expectation ajax request run after enable button. Please read about promise or send callback function in runCode. If you share your runCode with us then we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a promise or a callback function for `$('.btn-run').prop('disabled', false)` - sharing your `runCode` would help if possible.

You AJAX callback should look something like below. URL will be different, but `$('.btn-run').prop('disabled', false)` is being run on success. This should mean it will take effect.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "demo_test.txt", 
    success: function(result){
        $('.btn-run').prop('disabled', false)
    }
});
```